# How to implement encryption in android?

Tags: android, encryption

I have this application where I save device code, access token, and refresh token. And I want to add encryption to them. But I never tried it on android so if it would be lovely if you can share me a sample or some tips. I found the following library but don't know if its good. Since Im new to encryption in android, I would love to hear from you!

https://github.com/KazaKago/Cryptore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with AES encryption

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

public class AES256Cipher {

    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] ivBytes, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] textBytes) 
        throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException, 
            NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException {

        AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = null;
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, newKey, ivSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(textBytes);
    }

    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] ivBytes, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] textBytes) 
        throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException, 
        NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException {

        AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, newKey, ivSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(textBytes);
    }
}
```

Example application of the class:

```
String key = "e8ffc7e56311679f12b6fc91aa77a5eb";
byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] ivBytes = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

String plainText;
byte[] cipherData;
String base64Text;

//############## Request(crypt) ##############
plainText  = "crypt text!!";
cipherData = AES256Cipher.encrypt(ivBytes, keyBytes, plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
base64Text = Base64.encodeToString(cipherData, Base64.DEFAULT);
Log.d("encrypt", base64Text);   //BhSJd4mRRJo+fGzpxIOUNg==

//############## Response(decrypt) ##############
base64Text = "72XrlydqnUzVrDfDE7ncnQ==";
cipherData = AES256Cipher.decrypt(ivBytes, keyBytes, Base64.decode(base64Text.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT));
plainText = new String(cipherData, "UTF-8");
Log.d("dcrypt", plainText);         //I'm hungry
```

Comment: Thank you! How do you use it ? Do you use encrypt when saving and decrypt when using it? Im not savvy with encryption so some simple usage sample would be lovely!

Comment: If it helps you, can mark my answer as accepted? An upvote would be appreciated! Thanks @Nancy!

Comment: Thank you DearWolfe! It looks great! I will try them out now and see how it goes! I might ask you some questions if I find something hard :)

Comment: No problem @Nancy :)

Comment: Oh one more thing, what should I do if I want random strings each time if I try to encrypt the data  ? How will I do that? Currently only //BhSJd4mRRJo+fGzpxIOUNg== comes back....

Comment: And my current android is min16 but will AES work fine?

Comment: This code is quite bad with quite a few issues: 1. The key is supposed to be randomly generated and should not be a string without encoding. 2. The IV is not secret, but it needs to be *unpredictable* for CBC mode. Do not use a static IV. Just write the randomly chosen IV in front of the ciphertext so that it can be used for decryption. 3. There is no ciphertext authentication! That way, you cannot detect (malicious) changes to your ciphertexts. Just use an Encrypt-then-MAC scheme with HMAC-SHA256.

Comment: Also, you should refrain from answering such open ended questions.